# Key presser for Online Game

Tags: c#

I want to write an auto key presser for an online game. For this I tried to use function below :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVt, byte bscan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

This function works for applications like chrome,notepad,office etc. however keys didnt work in game window.

İs there any stronger way to simulate a key press event? I don't know how to simulate a key in a specific window. If I do it will the keys work?

Comment: You could always use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: I don't think we should help you here, because a clickbot in an online game is cheating

Comment: Why not just refactor the "stuff" that get executed when the key is pressed into a new method, then just call that method when you want to mimic the key-press event?

Comment: @Raubi was about to say so. you should better reformulate. Some games does not condamn this though

Comment: @Raubi clicker program is NOT COUNT AS CHEATING in my game.There are many programs which can already do what I want. I just want to practice myself to write a similar program. So dont charge me for cheating please...

Answer (score 0):

[SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Yes, you'll have to reference WindowsForms.